# How do i host a Server so people can find it?

Tags: java, hosting, server, kryonet

Ok so basically I am using KryoNet for the Server-Client communication , and they connect just fine and do what i want them to do in test scenarios. But when i try to connect from a different Network or even a different PC in the same Network the client cant seem to find the Server...

Server

```
static Server server;
//i dont even send on udp...
static int udpPort = 80, tcpPort = 5190;

public static void main() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Creating the server...");
    server = new Server();
    server.getKryo().register(SOME.class);

    server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), tcpPort), new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), udpPort));

    server.start();
    server.addListener(new ServerProgram());
```

And the Client

```
static Client client;
static int udpPort = 80, tcpPort = 5190;

public void connect(String ip) throws InterruptedException {

    client = new Client();
    client.getKryo().register(SOME.class);
    client.addListener(this);

    new Thread(client).start();

    try {
        client.connect(12000, ip, tcpPort, udpPort);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I noticed the Server is always created on my "local" address (192.168.0.***), so is there any way to make the Server more public or do my clients have to use something like [Hamatchi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_(software)) ?

Comment: do you have multiple network interfaces/IPs for the local PC? If you do, you'd have to explicitly list which interface/IP to bind to, instead of letting java choose for you. binding the "inside only" network won't help if you want outsiders to connect.

Comment: How do i bind to a specific interface/IP (which is the right one and where can i find the list of all the IPs [ipconfig /all ?]) ? Like how do i bind my server to the external IP what everyone can lookup/find to connect to the server ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide the host address in your server code on Kryonet. Your computer network has its own IP address which is used by Kryonet when you start the server.

So what I mean is rather than doing this

```
server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), tcpPort), new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), udpPort));
```

You can simply do

```
server.bind(timeOut, tcpPort, udpPort);
```

So on client code, when you start the client you put in the IP address (`127.0.0.1`) in case where both client and server are on same network.

In the case when server and client are on different networks, you need to get the external IP of the computer(network) on which your game server is hosted. Lets say for example your server is hosted on computer(network) with IP '`xxx.x.x.x`'. In your client code you will have `client.connect(xxx.x.x.x, TCP_PORT_SERVER_LISTENING_ON, UDP_PORT_SERVER_LISTENING_ON)`

And on Server

All you have to do on server is `server.bind(TIMEOUT, TCP_PORT, UDP_PORT_IF_YOU_USING)`

Also if you want to host the server on your computer, you need to do port forwarding.

To find the IP address of the server on which your KryoServer is hosted, you can go to [Find IP Address](http://www.myipaddress.com/show-my-ip-address/) on the server computer, then use this IP address in the client.